# React rendering a table, it takes so much time on scripting?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When rending a table in react, it takes so much time to render for scripting.
Is anyone fixed the same issue before?
Nearly 10000 records need to display in table.

[Performance from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6yO6.png)

Comment: A table with a thousand rows will always be kind of slow, if you render it with JavaScript, it's even slower. See https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/hy7jgz/react_is_slow_when_rendering_a_big_list/ which has a link to https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need virtualization to increase performance. The idea behind this is to render only the rows that are visible, effectively lazy load.

One library I would recommend that is lightweight and actively maintained is `react-window`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window

It is a complete rewrite of `react-virtualized` and was written with the intend of being smaller and faster.
Here is some example usage:

```
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
      <List
        className="List"
        height={height}
        itemCount={1000}
        itemSize={35}
        width={width}
      >
        {Row}
      </List>
    )}
  </AutoSizer>
```

[image: Edit bvaughn/react-window: fixed-size-list-vertical (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Hi it’s hard for browser to render so much data in one pass you need some virtualisation for the table, like this lib https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Answers should not only have links. You should show an example.